# Why do I fail empty-case test in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, isnullorempty

EDIT: problem solved, thank you guys. And thank you for other tips too!

I'm doing a 4kyu kata in CodeWars called "Snail" (using JAVA). Everything works fine, all tests are passed instead of one - "empty case".

The log for this tests says:

```
[[]] should be sorted to []
```

So I guess, that "if an array is empty, I am supposed to return an empty array as well".

Below I present the beginning of my method:

```
public static int[] snail(int[][] array) { 
    if ((array.length==0)) {
        int[] result  = new int[0]; 
        return result;
    }      

    if ((array==null)) {
        int[] result  = null;
        return result;
    }
```

I also tried to return null for both cases, then I tried to return empty-array in both cases too...

Any ideas what to do to pass this empty-case-test?

Comment: just note that `array` will never be `null` at your second test - the first test would fail with a `NullPointerException` if `array` is `null`. (change the order of the tests)

Comment: `[[]]` is not an empty array.

Comment: Wouldn't [[]] be an array containing an empty (0 length) array? in which case outer array would in fact not have length = 0, but 1.

Comment: what luk2302 and Worthless meant is that `array.length != 0 && array[0].length == 0`

Comment: Hey guys, thank you very much! I managed to solve (with your tips) it and now I see where I was mistaken. 
The solution that worked was obviously that one:
if (array.length != 0 && array[0].length == 0) {int[] result  = new int[0]; return result;} 
So I forgot to check the second-dimension of the array, what a shame. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the outer array contains the inner array, so it's length equals 1 - isn't it? The inner array does not contain anything, so that one should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `if` condition evaluates to `true` *iff* the method is called with an array that was initialized like `new int[0][]` - where `array.length` is `0`. The test log is telling you to consider a case, where `array.length` is `1` and `array[0].length` is `0`, e.g. where someone has initialized and assigned the array like

```
int[][] array = new int[1][];
array[0] = new int[0];
```

Just for readability - your `if` conditions each have an extra pair of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to determine the problem in your code:

1. Read the instructions.
2. Recognize that [] is not `null`.
3. Look at your code;
   observe that you are returning null when the input is empty.
4. Accept that [] is not `null`.
5. Return and empty array when the input is empty.
6. Understand that `array.length` is guaranteed to throw a NullPointerException when `array` is null.
7. Test for `null` before you attempt to dereference the `array` parameter.